Calculating the Derivative of a Complex Vector Function
I am trying to calculate the derivative of the function $$f(x) = x^T a (x^T a)^* = x^T a x^H a^* = x^T a a^H x^*$$, where $(.)^T$, $(.)^H$, and $(.)^*$ represent the transpose, Hermitian (conjugate transpose), and complex conjugate operations respectively. The column vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are complex vectors.
I understand that the derivative of the function $$f(x) = x^T a a^T x$$ is $$2 a^T a x$$ in the real domain. However, I am unsure how to extend this to the complex domain, especially when dealing with complex conjugates.

Define the scalar variable $\beta\;$ (and its conjugate)
$$\eqalign{
\def\q{\quad} \def\b{\beta}
\b &= a^Tx \q&\implies\q \,d\b\;=a^T\,dx \\
\b^* &= a^Hx^* \q&\implies\q d\b^*=a^Hdx^* \\
}$$
Then the differential of the posted function is
$$\eqalign{
f &= \b^*\b \\
df &= \b^*d\b \;+\; \b\:d\b^* \\
 &= \b^*a^Tdx \;+\; \b\,a^H dx^* \\
 &= (\b^*a)^Tdx \;+\; (\b\,a^*)^T dx^* \q\q\q \\
}$$
and the respective gradients (in the Wirtinger sense) are
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad fx &= \b^*a, \q\q
\grad f{x^*} &= \b\,a^* \;\equiv\; \left(\grad fx\right)^* \\
}$$
